# Javascript: Download data to file from content within the page

Tags: javascript, file, download, local

setting is the following:
I have a homepage where I display a diagram that has been constructed using comma seperated values from within the page. I'd like to give users the possibility to download the data as cvs-file without contacting the server again. (as the data is already there)
Is this somehow possible? I'd prefer a pure JavaScript solution.

So far I've discovered: http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html but it involves flash which I'd like to avoid.

I can't imagine this question hasn't been asked before. I'm sorry to double post, but it seems I've used the wrong keywords or something - I haven't found a solution in these forums.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**:

Time certainly changes things ;-) When I first answered this question **IE8** was the latest IE browser available (Nov 2010) and thus there was no cross browser way to accomplish this without a round trip to the server, or using a tool requiring Flash.

[@Zectburno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7439083/6144) will get you what you need now, however for historical context be aware of which IE browsers support which feature.

- btoa() is undefined in IE8 and IE9
- Blob is available in IE10+

Be sure to test in the browsers you need to support. Even though the Blob example in the other answer should work in IE10+ it doesn't work for me just clicking the link (browser does nothing, no error)... only if I right click and save target as "file.csv" then navigate to the file and double-click it can I open the file.

[Test both approaches (btoa/Blob) in this JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/335t5aow/)
(here's the code)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="a" target="_blank">Download CSV (via btoa)</a>
  <script>
    var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
    var a = document.getElementById("a");
    a.href = "data:text/csv;base64," + btoa(csv);
  </script>
  <hr/>
  <a id="a2" download="Download.csv" type="text/csv">Download CSV (via Blob)</a>
  <script>
    var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
    var data = new Blob([csv]);
    var a2 = document.getElementById("a2");
    a2.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Original Answer**:

I don't think there is an option available for this.

I would just adjust your code such that if Flash 10+ is detected ([93% saturation as of September 2009](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify)) on the user's system, provide the Downloadify option, otherwise fallback to a server-side request.

Comment: Can dowloadify be invoked from javascript? It would be tricky to create a flash button to fit my design.

Comment: @TomášZato yes it can be invoked by JavaScript: https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

Comment: A don't see how's that an answer to my question. I've read the "documentation", however my question was if the download can be triggered from javascript. That's unfortunately [impossible](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify/issues/20) - the Downloadify button must be clicked.

Comment: The click is required, but downloadify is not!

Comment: Please note that btoa() will fail with error when called on UTF-8 character outside of 0x00-0xff range, as it expects individual bytes as the input. Solution is to first convert a string into a byte array (Uint8Array) like this: `const csvBytes = new TextEncoder().encode(csv);` and then `a.href = "data:text/csv;base64," + btoa(String.fromCodePoint(...csvBytes));` (sorry it's ugly, can't figure out how to format a code-block in the comments)

Answer (score 35):

Tested on Safari 5, Firefox 6, Opera 12, Chrome 26.

```
<a id='a'>Download CSV</a>
<script>
    var csv = 'a,b,c\n1,2,3\n';
    var a = document.getElementById('a');
    a.href='data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa(csv);
</script>
```

---

HTML5

```
<a id='a' download='Download.csv' type='text/csv'>Download CSV</a>
<script>
    var csv = 'a,b,c\n1,2,3\n';
    var data = new Blob([csv]);
    var a = document.getElementById('a');
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
</script>
```

Comment: This is what I use, however in Mozzila Firefox, it causes horrible laggs for large files (>6MB).

Comment: If the URL is too big, then the download will simply fail in Chrome.

Comment: It would be helpful to hear what you mean by "too big". How many MB are you trying to download? You might need to use the HTML 5 method since the older method can only handle ~4kB depending on browser.

Comment: For large files, the problem is that the html parser needs to parse the entire string which takes time...

Comment: @swift-lynx, I don't follow. There is no parsing, and much less, no html parsing involved that would take any substantial time.

Comment: This is not a good solution in general. Firstly, it assumes that the data is available at the start, else it has to be updated in the DOM anytime it changes. It also dumps the entire data into the HTML (as others warn as well). I recommend going with solutions that generate the data to download when requested (e.g. clicked) by the user, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19230668/4465895

Answer (score 31):

Simple solution :

```
function download(content, filename, contentType)
{
    if(!contentType) contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var blob = new Blob([content], {'type':contentType});
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = filename;
        a.click();
}
```

**Usage**

```
download("csv_data_here", "filename.csv", "text/csv");
```

Comment: `'application/octet-stream'` was the key for me :+1:

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is not possible: This is why Downloadify was created.

You could try linking to a [`data:URL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) containing CSV data, but there will be cross-browser trouble.

Answer (score 3):

```
function export(exportAs) {
    var csvText = tableRowsToCSV(this.headTable.rows);­
    csvText += tableRowsToCSV(this.bodyTable.rows);­
    //open the iframe doc for writing
    var expIFrame;
    if (strBrowser == "MSIE") expIFrame = document.exportiframe;
    else expIFrame = window.framesexportiframe;
    var doc = expIFrame.document;
    doc.open('text/plain', 'replace');
    doc.charset = "utf-8";
    doc.write(csvText);
    doc.close();
    var fileName = exportAs + ".txt";
    doc.execCommand("SaveAs", null, fileName);
}

function tableRowsToCSV(theRows) {
    var csv = "";
    var csvRow = "";
    var theCells;
    var cellData = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < theRows.length; r++) {
        theCells = theRows.item(r).cells;
        for (var c = 0; c < theCells.length; c++) {
            cellData = "";
            cellData = theCells.item(c).innerText;
            if (cellData.indexOf(",") != -1) cellData = "'" + cellData + "'";
            if (cellData != "") csvRow += "," + cellData;
        }
        if (csvRow != "") csvRow = csvRow.substring(1, csvRow.length);­
        csv += csvRow + "\n";
        csvRow = "";
    }
    return csv;
}
```

I found this code elsewhere, [here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/798389), previously

Comment: expIFrame = window.framesexportiframe; //there's no framesexportiframe property in window !

Answer (score 2):

If your users have up to date browsers, the new Blob object could help you.

Based on the example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Blob ("Blob constructor example usage"), you could do something like the following:

```
var typedArray = "123,abc,456"; //your csv as a string
var blob = new Blob([typedArray], {type: "text/csv"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.querySelector("#linktocsv"); // the id of the <a> element where you will render the download link
a.href = url;
a.download = "file.csv";
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:onDownload();">Download</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function onDownload() {
    document.location = 'data:Application/octet-stream,' +
                         encodeURIComponent(dataToDownload);
}
```

Taken from [How to Download Data as a File From JavaScript](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2012/01/how-to-download-data-as-a-file-from-javascript.html)

Comment: This is a simple solution, but as mentioned on the original source, it is not known yet of a way to give the download file a name. If anyone knows the solution to this problem, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The most comprehensive solution I have run across is using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/), handling many potential cross-browser issues for you with fallbacks.

It takes advantage of the `Blob` object as other posters have done, and the creator even creates a *Blob.js* polyfill in case you need to support browser versions that don't support `Blob`