# Export HTML table to csv file on client side

Tags: javascript, html

I had a html table on my webpage. I need an export functionality like, the user gets a choice of opening or saving it on his local machine upon button click. 
As i already had the data in table format ready, it needs to read it and export it on client side itself using browser capabilities with out any plugins (jquery,..). Pure JS would be really appreciated.

HTML Table on my webpage:

```
<table id="incidents">
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to export this table into a csv or excel sheet on the clients machine giving the options of open or save

Comment: don't think that's gonna happen, a browser cannot write or read files on the client

Comment: I think you can now write files with the HTML 5 File API

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the table markup?

Comment: I seen someone create a data url with the CSV data from a html table. I just can't find it anymore. But it is possible. Some urls http://somenotestoself.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/how-to-create-a-csv-file-in-javascript-and-get-the-save-as-dialog/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184944/javascript-download-data-to-file-from-content-within-the-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export to CSV using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html)

Answer (score 9):

Generate the contents of the CSV file as a string in JavaScript (I assume you're not asking SO to just write this code for you), then [encode it as Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript) and generate a [data: URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs) with the MIME type `text/csv`. Redirect the browser to that URI and it should trigger a download dialog for the user.