# Javascript or Flash export to CSV/Excel

Tags: javascript, json, flash, excel

Is there anyway to export JSON data to CSV/Excel without any interaction with the server side? Using Javascript only? or Flash? I'm currently using ZeroClipboard to copy the value into the clipboard but I'd like to open directly the generated value into Excel from the browser (FF, Chrome, IE, etc...).

Thx.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Answer (score 9):

Far and away, the cleanest, easiest export from tables to Excel is [Jquery DataTables Table Tools plugin](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/). You get a grid that sorts, filters, orders, and pages your data, and with just a few extra lines of code and two small files included, you get export to **Excel**, **PDF**, **CSV**, to **clipboard** and to the **printer**.

This is all the code that's required:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    } );
} );
```

So, quick to deploy, no browser limitations, no server-side language required, and most of all very EASY to understand. It's a win-win. The one thing it does have limits on, though, is strict formatting of columns.

Comment: Is there a way to have the open option when exporting ? strange but I can only save the excel document

Comment: Is it possible to get that TableTools export goodness without adding any of the DataTables features? I mean, I already have an HTML table with sorting and filtering and much more stuff (using other methods, not DataTables), now I only needed the export features...

Comment: I'm trying to use TableTools, but I want to use my own buttons rather than using swf buttons. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a foolproof way to do it client-side only on all browsers and file sizes. All solutions seem to use one of the following:

- Flash plugin (ex: Downloadify): bugs and not mobile compatible
- Data URL: limited IE support and size restrictions
- HTML5: Download methods not standardized across browsers.

Depending on your use case you might be able to get away with one of the above though. Here are some other posts on SO with more details.

- [Export HTML table to csv file on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780296/export-html-table-to-csv-file-on-client-side)
- [Export to csv in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery)

Note that this part of the answer from Ramandeep Singh is incorrect:

> So, quick to deploy, no browser limitations, no server-side language
>   required, and most of all very EASY to understand.

DataTables does use a flash plugin if you look at the code. It will not work on mobile browsers (iOS, recent Android devices without rooting, Windows 8 RT without hacks or MSFT approval process). Here is a post from their site as well: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/7563/export-to-csvpdf-without-tabletools/p1