# How to save a variable in .csv format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I have a variable in javascript the contents of which are valid for a `.csv` file. I want the user to save its contents in a file of his/her choice. I do the following:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="downloadCSV">Download CSV</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#downloadCSV').click(function () {
    var csvContent = generateCSV(); //The function generates a valid CSV
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    window.open(encodedUri);
});
```

This does two things that I don't want:

1. Opens another chrome tab.
2. just says 'download' in the windows pop up (Even the extension needs to be added manually). Instead of that I want it to have a default name with extension. Say `foobar.csv`

I have gone through similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533811/converting-variable-in-javascript-to-a-csv-file) but to no avail. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure, is it help to you, but check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: You can't do that with simple javascript.